# react-grid-layout resizableHandles don't work properly

Tags: reactjs, layout, grid, resize, handle

I'm using react-grid-layout and all of the handles BUT "s", "e" and "se" are working not as expected.

When dragging from the top-left corner - instead of going up and left it takes the bottom right corner and changes it.
Did anyone ever have the same problem and knows how to solve it?